# Implementing row level identification to all existing mappings(Automation)

Tags: etl, informatica-powercenter

I am trying to implement row level identification in the target in informatica.
The mappings are already present and links are already made but i want this change to be implemented in more than 1000 mappings. How can i do this without affecting the current mapping as it become very tedious to add column in expression in 1000 mappings manually. Is there a better way to do this. Please tell. If my question is not understood please ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very complex task. There is no out-of-the-box solution to accomplish that, I'm afraid. What you could do, is export all the mappings to XML and work on the exported definitions to add the required feature. Then import the definitions back. This however requires some analysis to understand the way mappings are built as well as the details of your requirement.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Actually i was thinking the same as if some mappings uses a similar kind of expressions then i can add the change i want to implement just by inserting that line in XML. But how should i implement that change thorugh coding. Any example like python or any other scripting?

Comment: You're asking for a lot... I will not provide a complete solution or do the task for you. That's a lot of work. I can HELP. Give it a try, let us know here if you come across some issues, get ADVICE. Not "the work done". That's best I can do.

Comment: Well thank you for answering...but i was not asking the solution or i didnt ask you to do that work for me. I am more capable of doing that on my own. But there is difference in saying and doing it. I just wanted to know if there was a simpler way of doing it. Well to tell u this i completed that work. Thank you for your encouragement and support.